# How to get the id on right click context menu in dojo Tree?

Tags: javascript, tree, contextmenu, dojo

I want to get the *node* **id** of Dojo's tree **on context menu** click.

I'm making a tree in Dojo like this. Here is the id - the first param.

```
 this.setData(
            [
{ id: '5', name:'root' , type:'continent' }, 
{ id: '6', name:'catalog 1', parent: '5' , type:'continent' }, 
{ id: '7', name:'catalog 2', parent: '5' , type:'continent' }, 
{ id: '8', name:'catalog 2.1', parent: '7' , type:'continent' }, 
{ id: '9', name:'child Catalog', parent: '8' , type:'continent' }, 
{ id: '10', name:'catalog 4', parent: '5' , type:'continent' } ]);
```

Here is my tree and menu init functions.
So, when I click with the right button on the tree - there is a context menu with a button. When I click that button - it triggers the **onClick** function. I want to receive that **id**.

```
     <script>
        function createMyTree()
        {
            var tree = new dijit.Tree({
                                        model: myModel,
                                        id: 'contextMenu'
                                        });
            tree.placeAt("myTree", "last");
            tree.startup();


            pMenu = new dijit.Menu({
                targetNodeIds:["contextMenu"]
            });

            pMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
                label:"Delete",
                iconClass:"dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconDelete",
                onClick: function(){
                    /// HERE I WANT MY id
                }
            }));

            pMenu.startup();
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: can you create a minimalistic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used dojo before, but I think you should use the [contextmeu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/contextmenu) event over onclick. From that you can get the `target` or `relatedTarget` and checking it with `button` property (the type of mouse button pressed; probably 2).

If that doesn't gives you a valid element, you can use [`document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) from the `event.screenX` and `event.screenY` to get the valid element.

Comment: the point is that dojo generates DOM from the input. So even when I read this HTML (the generated code of tree nodes) I don't see this ID - it's ommited e.g. no attribute contains it. So.. the situation is bad... I have to use some Dojo method, but I don't know witch and in the documentation is not said about this...

Comment: Yes of course - the code is in my question - there are two pieces. The first is the json data (there is the ID I want - the first param). The second is the javascript function that builds that tree. Do you need some more?

Comment: @DonAngeloAnnoni sorry, i was asking about a working demo. maybe something can be found from a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

I found it..
Thanks guys. If you have better suggestions please share it. :)

```
   var selectedObject = tree.get("selectedItems")[0];
   console.log("the id what I need", selectedObject.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

selector: '.dijitTreeNode' in Menu config options.